# "ssh_askpass exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass) no such file or directory" error when I try to push in Git repo using VS Code

Tags: ssh, git, 19.10, github, visual-studio-code

Don't know what happened. But all of sudden I can't push updates in GitHub. A month ago I used SSH keys to integrate VS Code with Github so that I do not have to type email & password every single time when I use to push updates to the Git repository.

*I think BleachBit has deleted some important files and this is happening.* **But** this is my *wild guess*. I can't confirm this. Because I didn't do anything other than that. VS Code used to work fine. Suddenly this is happening. I gotta be careful with Bleachbit **if** this is an act of Bleachbit. 
[image: Screenshot of the error message.]

Meanwhile, I am going nuts over for a week thinking how to solve this issue. If you had this issue, then do comment it out.

When I did `ls /usr/bin/ssh-askpass`, it say there is no file or folder. This might be the cause of the problem. But I do see these folders inside **/usr/bin** related to ssh:

 `ssh
 ssh-add  //is a file that supposed to be deleted when I unistalled ssh-askpass
 ssh-agent  //is a file
 ssh-argv0
 ssh-copy-id
 ssh-keygen
 ssh-keyscan`

Comment: Can you confirm that the file `ssh-askpass` is there or not?

Comment: @guillermochamorro How can I confirm this? I do see same three files inside .ssh in home folder: id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and known_hosts.

Comment: Try `ls /usr/bin/ssh-askpass `

Comment: @guillermochamorro It says no such file or directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think (& am 100%) I found my solution. 
If you use services like SSH keys, make sure you don't disable **SSH Key Agent**. It was a stupid mistake. A week ago, I tried to decrease my boot time by disabling all unwanted services that launch itself while booting. I read askubuntu post asked by someone to disable those services. Now I have realized it.

[image: Screenshot]

Lesson learned. Don't do anything which you **know** don't for sure. *Try not to disable other startup services related to SSH if you depend on it.* After enabling the service, you might have to **reboot**. Then you are good to go.

Comment: or invoke `ssh-add` once to get the agent running

Answer (score 20):

I had to do 2 things to get this solved.

1. As @Wan-Chap said above

   ```
    sudo apt install ssh-askpass
   ```
2. Use this command to add bitbucket.org (In my case it was Bitbucket)

   ```
    ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
   ```

Comment: instead of ">" you should use ">>" to append otherwise it will overwrite existing known hosts, which might not be a desirable outcome...

Comment: @efaruk Thanks for mentioning. I have updated.

Answer (score 7):

It seems your ssh-askpass is missing. Just re-install it by:

```sh
sudo apt install ssh-askpass
```

Comment: I already tried this solution. This is not a standard mechanism to solve this problem. The whole idea of having SSH keys is to make VS code push updates without having to enter a password like 1000 times. This does solve the problem but it will ask password in each push to git repo.