# ssh-askpass error appears sometimes

Tags: ssh

When I ssh to another host `hosta` and then connect yet to a further host `hostb`, everything works fine. Both hosts currently expect a passwd.

However, when I try to shortcut this intermediate host and put the next ssh as a parameter, I get the [often mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196164/ssh-askpass-exec-usr-libexec-openssh-ssh-askpass-no-such-file-or-directory-e) error:

```
$ ssh -X hosta ssh1 -X -1 login@hostb
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied.
```

All this seems to be related to the environment variables that are passed further on.

What is ssh here expecting? How can I fix this?

And, I have already added hostb to the known hosts on hosta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man ssh`:

```
 -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute
         arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
         very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
         options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Since you are running multiple ssh sessions you would use multiple `-t`'s.  They can be shortened by doing `ssh -tt`.  The command then would look like the following to force a pseudo-tty so you can enter passwords and see prompts on your connections.

```
ssh -tt -X hosta ssh1 -X -1 login@hostb
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Kind-of-a-solution:

Instead of executing the remote command directly, I added a `xterm -e` in front. In this manner it seems the right variables are here, and also the second prompt works.