# How to detect for a remote program that unity is running

Tags: unity, xserver

I have a legacy program (since 1992) on a dedicated remote machine as an X-client that while starting up tries to fix all kinds of oddities using `xmodmap` and the like. Starting with 18.04 I note that many of these fixes no longer work.

How can (or should) the X-client detect that unity is running on the X-server? Or, to put it differently: What information does unity offer to X-clients beyond xdpyinfo and the like?

The connecting X-servers are more than 50 of various configurations (XQuartz, Ubuntu, Cygwin, and many Linuxes I never heard of before). They connect [indirectly](https://askubuntu.com/q/1224457/119823) to the X-client otherwise known as a server.

Comment: Is it though a SSH tunnel? How about checking the x server environment variables?

Comment: @user.dz: Thank you, to my understanding that requires an extra, non-portable script in the beginning.

Comment: It seems to me quite not obvious, How can X11 server, at display level, show info  about another separate part of the X system. Display Manager (DM) is seen only as root window with respect to X server. Instead of `xdpyinfo` see with `xwininfo -root` witch is a command to show information about windows. Look for `_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK` in root window  Then  `_NET_WM_NAME`  for that child window. If they are set with Unity. Ref: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s03.html#id2568237

Comment: @user.dz: In the olden tymes, the vendor information was an excellent hint.

Comment: I am not certain if @user.dz "x server environment variables" refer to the same as I posted in an answer.
And in that case, I am not certain why that won't be useful for you.
Perhaps you could be more specific about what broke, and what upgrade led to that.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Yes that what I was referring to. I'm curious which X setup OP has? There are many ways. Are both systems: Ubuntu, Version 18.04?

Comment: @user.dz - Agree. OP should specify a few points. Is it a single client machine, connecting to a single server? Or is his legacy program deployed across several clients and/or possibly connecting to several servers? Which OSs / session managers does he have in his systems?

Comment: @sancho: It's many (more that 50) with unknown systems connecting to one server behind. So I try to make the access as simple as possible.

Comment: More than 50 client systems, with a single server?
If so, you know which session manager you have in your server, you could hardcode whatever you want to do (you did not specify the issue, so it is hard to tell/help).

Comment: @sancho: Maybe this is just the X terminology confusion. More than 50 persons connect with their own system which I do not control. They connect to one server (which is in X-terminology the client and which I control).

Comment: I suggest you put together a small schematics of the hard/soft components you have in your ecosystem...

Answer (score 2):

Note that you may have more than one session manager available at your server.
See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288545/handling-multiple-window-managers-multiple-xsessionrc-files .
I am not certain if any combination of session managers provides a stable ecosystem, though.
I have even seen mixed comments about having 2 different session managers running at the same time in different clients, although I never tried it myself.

So I am not certain if you want to check whether unity is available, it is currently running, or if the session you are connecting to is managed by unity.

You could start checking the values of a few environment variables. E.g., `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`, `GDMSESSION`, `DESKTOP_SESSION`.

I guess you are not interested in the output of

```
ps -ef | grep -i unity
```